# Touchpad not working Thinkpad 440s

Tags: mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

My touchpad partially stopped working after an update. I have a Thinkpad T440s. I can use the trackpoint and only use the touchpad to left click.

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]


 xinput list-props 12
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (136):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (138): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (261): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (262):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (263):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (264):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (253):    2, 7
    Device Node (254):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (265): 0, 0
    Evdev Axis Calibration (266):   <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (267):  0
    Axis Labels (268):  "Abs MT Position X" (287), "Abs MT Position Y" (288), "Abs MT Pressure" (289), "Abs Tool Width" (286), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0)
    Button Labels (269):    "Button Left" (139), "Button Unknown" (256), "Button Unknown" (256), "Button Wheel Up" (142), "Button Wheel Down" (143)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (270): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (271):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (272):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (273): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (274): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (275):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (276):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (277):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (278):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (279):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (280):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (281): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (282):  0
```

I don't know how to start debugging this. Any help would be appreciated. I am running 14.04